# GroupBy Pandas with ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am working on a dataset which looks something like this:

```
ID  Amount Type
1   50    A
1   1000  A
1   500   B
1   200   B
2   1000  A
2   500   B
```

I am trying to do 2 things: Find length of longest sequence of each type and find ratio of A/B and B/A for those sequences for each ID.

Ratio attribute explanation: Calculate the total amount in the longest sequence for each ID(say length n). If the sequence is that of Type A, then get ratio with immediate amount of type B(n+1 amount). If sequence is of type B, then get ratio with the immediate predecessor of type A(n-1 amount).

So in the case I have mentioned the final result looks like this:

```
ID Longest_Sequence_A Longest_Sequence_B Ratio_A_B  Ratio B_A
1  2                  2                  0.47        0.7
2  1                  1                  0.5         0.5
```

Explanation of Row 1: Longest Sequences are simply the length of the longest sequence of type A and type B.

For Ratio A_B: This is case 1 as defined earlier, so sum of all type A's in the longest sequence is calculated(1050) , then a ratio is taken with the immediate successive B type amount(500), ratio 500/1050=0.47

For Ratio B_A: This is case 2 as defined earlier, so sum of all type B's in the longest sequence is calculated(700), then a ratio is taken with the immediate predecessor of type A amount(1000),
ratio 700/1000=0.7

This is a fairly complex issue I am unable to solve. Would appreciate it a lot if someone helps with this.

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. What have you done so far?

Comment: It is not a homework question(a few years too late for that) ,I am working on transaction dataset to build a model. I have tried using GroupBy but then I am not sure what lambda function to pass for the ratio thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt:

```
def ratios(df):
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    groups = (df.Type != df.Type.shift(1)).cumsum()
    result = {}
    for t in ('A', 'B'):
        if t in df.Type.values:
            max_num = groups[df.Type.eq(t)].mode().iat[-1]
            max_group = df[groups.eq(max_num)]
            result[f'Longest_Sequence_{t}'] = len(max_group)
            amounts = max_group.Amount.sum()
            idx = max_group.index
            ratio = None
            if t == 'A':
                if idx[-1] != df.index[-1] and amounts != 0:
                    ratio = df.Amount.at[idx[-1] + 1] / amounts
            elif t == 'B':
                if idx[0] != df.index[0]:
                    denom = df.Amount.at[idx[0] - 1]
                    if denom != 0:
                        ratio = amounts / denom
            result[f'Ratio_{t}'] = ratio
        else:
            result[f'Longest_Sequence_{t}'] = 0
            result[f'Ratio_{t}'] = None
    return pd.DataFrame([result])

df = df.groupby('ID').apply(ratios).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
```

The result for dataframe

```
   ID  Amount Type
0   1      50    A
1   1    1000    A
2   1     500    B
3   1     200    B
4   2    1000    A
5   2     500    B
```

is

```
    Longest_Sequence_A  Ratio_A  Longest_Sequence_B  Ratio_B
ID                                                          
1                    2  0.47619                   2      0.7
2                    1  0.50000                   1      0.5
```

The naming and ordering of the columns is a bit different, but this shouldn't matter.

---

Some explanations (I'm using the whole dataframe as sample):

This `groups = (df.Type != df.Type.shift(1)).cumsum()` identifies the sequences:

```
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
Name: Type, dtype: int64
```

For `groups[df.Type.eq('A')]`

```
0    1
1    1
4    3
Name: Type, dtype: int64
```

`.mode()` identifies the `'A'`-sequence number for the sequence of maximal length (in case there are maximal sequences of equal length the `.iat[-1]` selects the last one):

```
0    1
dtype: int64
```

Now here with `max_num == 1` this `max_group = df[groups.eq(max_num)]` selects the respective group with the index from `df` (the last point is important for the rest):

```
   ID  Amount Type
0   1      50    A
1   1    1000    A
```

The rest is trying to follow your calculation instructions and thereby taking care of the edge cases. The use of an index `idx` relative to `df` allows to step back and forth in `df` to select the other values needed for the ratios. (At the beginnig of the function the index is transformed into the standard index, just to make sure, because I want to be able to use `+/-` on it.)

Comment: This does not work. I am getting an IndexError for the line:
max_num = groups[df.Amount.eq(t)].mode().iat[-1]
     
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: It is failing for some edge case from what I can tell, maybe the case where it only has amounts of a single type

Comment: My suspicion: There's an `ID` in the frame that has only one sort of `Type`-values. I've adjusted the code for that case.

Comment: Sorry, just saw your last comment: That's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: This works now thanks. Probably will come up with a work around for the ratio=None thing depending upon my use case. Still super helpful! Thanks